# Firebase Authentication create user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to programatically add new users in firebase auth service with phone no and email (both providers attached to each other). Is there anyway I can do it without verifying them and maybe through nodejs (reactjs will also work, but node is preferred as I building an api to do some custom task after user is created) ?

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved by: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).